# What is the name of this plant growing up in my Garden

Tags: houseplants

I am wondering what kind of plant could be this?

[image]

It came up by itself.
Is it useful to leave it in my Garden?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a palm, a feather palm. It is hard to exactly say what species, do you have palms around your garden somewhere in nearby?

Comment: no any palms around, that is why I am wondering from where it came.